# NodeJS DNS Reverse Lookup

Tags: node.js

I need to get the host name of the client from its IP. I tried to use Node's DNS Reverse module and it works for external IP's but not internal IP's.

```
const dns = require('dns');
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
dns.reverse(ip,  function(err, hostnames) {
  if (err) console.log(`Couldn't reverse IP ${ip}:`, err);
  else     console.log(`IP ${ip} maps to:`, hostnames);
});
```

I get error `ENOTFOUND` for my internal IP. But if I use 8.8.8.8, I will get a host name. Am I missing something with my configuration? I have tested on this on the server using CMD to get the host name by `ping -a [internal IP]` and it works.

Comment: As per the documentation  dns.lookup() uses operating system utilities , like what a ping does , whereas  dns.resolve() and dns.reverse() always perform a DNS query on the network. The latter might not be reaching the DNS severs in internal client network. You could try to tweak dns.lookupService(address, port, callback) to get what you want. Refer : https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations

Comment: If you perform `dig -x localip`, what do you get?